# Merge Multiple .sql Table Dump Files Into a Single SQL file

Tags: mysql

I would like to merge multiple .sql databases with similar tables into one single file. I used the below method suggested by another person on this issue.

[Merge Multiple .sql Table Dump Files Into A Single File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582660/merge-multiple-sql-table-dump-files-into-a-single-file/17582801#17582801)

I ran this method suggested by @Bill Karwin but still getting an error when running the database on the server indicating the below error.

ERROR 1136 (21s01) at line 1195: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: that only works if the tables are identical, yout aren't, so fix that

Comment: Hi nbk. The tables I have are identical. The databases are different but the structure is the same as the Databases are extracted from 3 PHPIPAM DB servers.

Comment: the clearly arent' one table has at least one short. If you get that message, the problem is clear compare the databases

Comment: Hi nbk. Thanks for the input. Yes you are right I was able to find that the fields in the tables are different. What do you think is the best way to do it? I am using MariaDB for my sql database. Is there a tool from where it can be done easily as I have multiple tables to rectify.

Comment: Simply add the missing columns, so that both fit.